# More then one mathematical operation on 2D array causes incorrect values inside 2D array

Tags: c#, dct

I am trying to find a cause of trouble in my code. `FDCTHorizontal` transforms all numbers inside 2D array and `IDCTHorizontal` should transform them back.

Methods work ONLY if one methematical operation is done on one, same element inside of each method. If two operations are made, returned 2D array from `IDCTHorizontal` is not the same that entered `FDCTHorizontal`.

Argument `differences` represenets a row in 2D array. Argument `Y` and `X` represent output row values.

Why can't I use more then one mathematical operations in both methods?

Code:

```
public static void FDCTHorizontal(ref int[] differences, ref int[] Y)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < differences.Length; j += 8) //split by 8
    {
        double[] X = new double[8];

        int indexCounter = 0;
        for (int _ = j; _ < j + 8; _++)
        {
            X[indexCounter] = differences[_];
            indexCounter++;
        }

        //1. stage
        double X0value = X[0];
        double X1value = X[1];
        double X2value = X[2];
        double X3value = X[3];
        double X4value = X[4];
        double X5value = X[5];
        double X6value = X[6];
        double X7value = X[7];

        //X[0] = X[0] + X7value; //if not commented, value when calling inverse method will not be the same
        X[7] = -X[7] + X0value;

        Y[j + 0] = Convert.ToInt32(X[0]);
        Y[j + 4] = Convert.ToInt32(X[1]);
        Y[j + 2] = Convert.ToInt32(X[2]);
        Y[j + 6] = Convert.ToInt32(X[3]);
        Y[j + 7] = Convert.ToInt32(X[4]);
        Y[j + 3] = Convert.ToInt32(X[5]);
        Y[j + 5] = Convert.ToInt32(X[6]);
        Y[j + 1] = Convert.ToInt32(X[7]); //switched order
    }
}

public static void IDCTHorizontal(ref int[] changedDifferences, ref int[] X)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < changedDifferences.Length; j += 8)
    {
        double[] Y = new double[8];
        int indexCounter = 0;
        for (int _ = j; _ < j + 8; _++)
        {
            Y[indexCounter] = changedDifferences[_];
            Y[indexCounter] = Y[indexCounter];
            indexCounter++;
        }

        double Y0value = Y[0];
        double Y1value = Y[1];
        double Y2value = Y[2];
        double Y3value = Y[3];
        double Y4value = Y[4];
        double Y5value = Y[5];
        double Y6value = Y[6];
        double Y7value = Y[7];

        //Y[0] = Y[0] - Y1value; //if not a comment, returned array does not have the right values
        Y[1] = -Y[1] + Y0value;

        X[j + 0] = Convert.ToInt32(Y[0]);
        X[j + 1] = Convert.ToInt32(Y[4]);
        X[j + 2] = Convert.ToInt32(Y[2]);
        X[j + 3] = Convert.ToInt32(Y[6]);
        X[j + 4] = Convert.ToInt32(Y[7]);
        X[j + 5] = Convert.ToInt32(Y[3]);
        X[j + 6] = Convert.ToInt32(Y[5]);
        X[j + 7] = Convert.ToInt32(Y[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Y[indexCounter] = Y[indexCounter];` in your first loop inside `IDCTHorizontal` smells fishy.

Answer (score 0):

Independently of the correctness of your algorithms, you have a bigger issue: you are performing a banker's rounding in both tranformations. You can't expect both operations to be reversible, because rounding, in general, isn't:

Suppose the following transformation: `f(x) = x + 1.5` and the opposite `g(x) = x - 1.5`. Applying both transformations is obviously a noop: `g(f(x)) = x + 1.5 - 1.5 = x`.

However, if we add rounding to it, the behavior changes:

```
f´(x) = BankersRound(x + 1.5)
g´(x) = BankersRound(x - 1.5)

x = 3
f´(3) = BankersRound(4.5) = 4 //round to the nearest even number
g´(f(3)) = BankersRound(4 - 1.5) = BankersRound(2.5) = 2 //round to the nearest even number
```

UPDATE: Ok, this is not the issue because, as RufusL correctly points out, you are only performing additions and subtractions so rounding shouldn't be an issue in this particual case. But this obviously begs the question: why are you using a `double` array to begin with? If you are adding and subtracting integers, then use an array of ints! (or longs if you are expecting potenitial overflows in intermediate operations).

Comment: That makes sense, but since the input to both methods is integers, and the only operations being performed is addition and subtraction, can you explain how rounding would affect these "whole" numbers?

Comment: @RufusL Lol, good point, I should have checked the algorithm! I'll leave the answer, it doesn't hurt.